# Excel.exe stays in memory after macro finishes

Tags: process, excel, vba

I'm using VBA automation from an **Access 2010** to create charts using **Excel 2010**. My code works fine, but leaves an orphan Excel.exe process running. I have traced the problem to a call to an Excel VBA function in a separate module. If I eliminate the call to this function, the Excel process is closed when the codes finishes. The function is Chip Pearson's `FindAll` with modifications to get it to run in Access, such as declaring ranges as `Excel.Range` and explicitly referencing the `Union` method as `Excel.Application.Union`. How do I need to modify this function so that is does not leave an orphaned Excel process running?

The following code binds the Excel application in the main procedure:

```
Dim oApp As New excel.Application
Dim oBook As excel.Workbook
Dim oSheet As excel.Worksheet

Set oBook = oApp.Workbooks.Add
Set oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)
```

Then, at the end:

```
oBook.Close False
oApp.Quit

Set oSheet = Nothing
Set oBook = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing
```

And I am calling FindAll using this line:

```
      b = FindAll(oSheet.Range("a2", oSheet.Range("a2").End(xlDown)), strWellID).Rows.Count
```

The `FindAll` function is below:

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' modFindAll
' By Chip Pearson, chip@cpearson.com. www.cpearson.com
' 24-October-2007
' This module is described at www.cpearson.com/Excel/FindAll.aspx
' Requires Excel 2000 or later.
'
' This module contains two functions, FindAll and FindAllOnWorksheets that are use
' to find values on a worksheet or multiple worksheets.
'
' FindAll searches a range and returns a range containing the cells in which the
'   searched for text was found. If the string was not found, it returns Nothing.

' FindAllOnWorksheets searches the same range on one or more workshets. It return
'   an array of ranges, each of which is the range on that worksheet in which the
'   value was found. If the value was not found on a worksheet, that worksheet's
'   element in the returned array will be Nothing.
'
' In both functions, the parameters that control the search have the same meaning
' and effect as they do in the Range.Find method.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Function FindAll(SearchRange As Excel.Range, _
                FindWhat As Variant, _
                Optional LookIn As XlFindLookIn = xlValues, _
                Optional LookAt As XlLookAt = xlWhole, _
                Optional SearchOrder As XlSearchOrder = xlByRows, _
                Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False) As Range
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' FindAll
    ' This searches the range specified by SearchRange and returns a Range object
    ' that contains all the cells in which FindWhat was found. The search parameters to
    ' this function have the same meaning and effect as they do with the
    ' Range.Find method. If the value was not found, the function return Nothing.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Dim FoundCell As Excel.Range
    Dim FirstFound As Excel.Range
    Dim LastCell As Excel.Range
    Dim ResultRange As Excel.Range

    With SearchRange
        Set LastCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    End With

    'On Error Resume Next
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set FoundCell = SearchRange.Find(What:=FindWhat, _
            after:=LastCell, _
            LookIn:=LookIn, _
            LookAt:=LookAt, _
            SearchOrder:=SearchOrder, _
            MatchCase:=MatchCase)

    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then

        Set FirstFound = FoundCell
        Set ResultRange = FoundCell
        Set FoundCell = SearchRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)

        Do Until False ' Loop forever. We'll "Exit Do" when necessary.
            If (FoundCell Is Nothing) Then
                Exit Do
            End If

            If (FoundCell.Address = FirstFound.Address) Then
                Exit Do
            End If

            Set ResultRange = Excel.Application.Union(ResultRange, FoundCell)
            Set FoundCell = SearchRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)
        Loop
    End If

    Set FindAll = ResultRange

    'added below

    Set ResultRange = Nothing
    Set FoundCell = Nothing
    Set FirstFound = Nothing
    Set LastCell = Nothing
    Set SearchRange = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Before passing `SearchRange` to the above function, how are you binding with the Excel application? The reason Excel leaves an instance behind is because you are not `Flushing the Toilet` ;) You have to quit the Excel Application and set it to nothing after the above function is run.

Comment: When the main procedure finishes, I do have the following to flush the toilet.
oBook.Close False
oApp.Quit

Set oSheet = Nothing
Set oBook = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing

Comment: Try this. Replace `Excel.Application.Union(ResultRange, FoundCell)` with `oApp.Union(ResultRange, FoundCell)` and try it...

Comment: That gives a runtime error 424 "Object Required" when it hits the Union line.

Comment: Try this... change `Function FindAll(SearchRange As Excel.Range, _
                FindWhat As Variant,.....` to `Function FindAll(oAp as Excel.Application, SearchRange As Excel.Range, _
                FindWhat As Variant, ....` and then use the function as `b = FindAll(oApp, oSheet.Range("a2",....` if this still doesn't work, then I will write one small sample to test it :)

Comment: Passing the Excel application to the function as you suggested worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great! You might want to post the solution as answer and accept it so that it may help anyone who has the same problem?

Comment: Will do, but I have to wait 8 hours since I'm a new registered user!

Comment: No worries. You can post after 8 hrs ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout `You have to quit the Excel Application and set it to nothing after the above function is run` how is that possible when the code has `Dim ... As New` in it? `oApp` will keep getting reinstantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Jimmy Pena and Siddharth Rout provide excellent comments as to how help remove the phantom excel process.

I only wanted to add that while I would not necessarily recommend it in all cases, if it is a persistent issue and you are looking for a quick "fix" while you troubleshoot, you can brute-force the close, as noted in this SO question: [VBA script to close every instance of Excel except itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526228/vba-script-to-close-every-instance-of-excel-except-itself)

```
Sub ForceExcelExit()

Dim BruteForce As String

BruteForce = "TASKKILL /F /IM excel.exe"
Shell BruteForce, vbHide

End Sub
```

Testing reveals a swift if not particularly elegant end to the process.

You can also use an iterative loop to end such processes in a slightly more elegant manner - but still using system process methods, rather than application / application interface methods: [HOW TO close Excel instance started by mail merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439250/how-to-close-excel-instance-started-by-mail-merge)

While I do not endorse either of these methods as a blanket solution to leaving instances active due to incomplete or insufficient error-checking, code encapsulation or general callback, method use, variable instantiation or other programmatic issues, it is a fix in cases where a fix is needed.